# All my Time Machine windows are black

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

[image]

That was supposed to be my finder window with my backups over time but I only see black screens. :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to Finder and select your Time Capsule in the Shared list in the sidebar. Browse to the sparse bundle that contains your backups and mount it, then give it a few seconds and open Time Machine.

Comment: @grgarside I just encountered the same problem.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Yes I believe it is. I haven't experienced the problem in 10.10 though.